# How do I assign a variable php redirect based on the initial url input after a user has accepted terms/responsibility message?

Tags: php, redirect

see: http://www.eat-drink-etc.com/

I have this code in the header of all the sites' pages:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['responsibility'])) {
    //echo '{redirect="responsibility/message"}';
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = '{site_url}responsibility/message'</script>";
}?>
```

Redirecting to mydomain/responsibility/message if the user is a first time (or hasn't visited recently) visitor to the site.

In the message page I have the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
/*if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
$_SESSION = array();*/?>
```

```
function setcookielive($name, $value='', $expire=0, $path='', $domain='', $secure=false, $httponly=false) {
    //set a cookie as usual, but ALSO add it to $_COOKIE so the current page load has access
    $_COOKIE[$name] = $value;
    return setcookie($name,$value,$expire,$path,$domain,$secure,$httponly);
}
if(isset($_POST['set'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        /*if(setcookielive("responsibility", "confirmed", time()+60*60*24*30*24, "/")) {
        }*/
        $_SESSION['responsibility'] = 'confirmed';
        echo '{redirect="/"}';
    }
    else {
        /*if(setcookielive("responsibility", "confirmed", time()+60*60*24, "/")) {
        }*/
        $_SESSION['responsibility'] = 'confirmed';
        echo '{redirect="/"}';
    }
}?>
```

The page uses a from input to enter the site:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="set" value="set" />
<input type="hidden" name="remember" value="true" />
<input type="image" src="{site_url}images/elements/enter-btn.png" width="95" height="26" alt="Enter" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

Example: if a user goes to http://www.eat-drink-etc.com/articles/fi_europe_ni_2011
they will be redirected to the responsibility/message page. When enter is clicked the user is taken to the home page. (as specified)

How do I redirect to the originally targeted url??? eg. ../articles/fi_europe_ni_2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fisrtly, why are you performing the browser redirect through Javascript (client side) when you could do the same thing server side with a `header("Location: $url;");` call?

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['responsibility'])) {
  ob_end_clean();
  header("Location: $url; ");
  exit;
}
// etc... you would need to call ob_end_flush(); before ending the page if you plan to have output here.
```

Something like that, to start with.

To answer your question: You would need to retrieve the current URL and store it as a session property before redirecting to the messages page.  To amend my above example:

```
 <?php

ob_start();
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_url'] = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

// etc

You could then access this URL on the confirmation page by again performing a header redirect like this:

```
header("Location: {$_SESSION['last_url']}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['responsibility'])) {
  header("Location: /responsibility/message?refer=" . urlencode($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
}?>
```

And on your responsibility page you do something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['set'])) {
  if(isset($_POST['remember'])) {
    $_SESSION['responsibility'] = 'confirmed';

    if( isset($_GET['refer']) )
      header("Location: " . $_GET['refer']);
  }
}
```

You might need to add a few checks to the $_GET['refer'] so that it won't get abused but you get the idea

Comment: "Might" need? Are you in the practice of creating blatantly vulnerable scripts?

Comment: @reformed Well I should have used "should" instead of "might". English is not my native language and I am probably not the best in it. Still the point has been made.